# Java RMI: how to make client stub method called on server print message on client screen?

Tags: java, rmi

I'm making a chat with rmi in Java. I have one server object and at least two clients objects. When a client send a message to the server calling the method recebeMensagem remotely, the server must print that message on all clients' screen (except the client that sent the message).

The client class has a method `printMenssagem(Mensagem msg)`, that is called remotely by the server. The problem is that that method is printing on server's screen. How do I make to print the message on client's screen instead?

Server.java:

```
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Server implements ChatServer {

    private ArrayList<String> listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
    private static int port = 5002;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Server obj = new Server();
            ChatServer stub = (ChatServer) 
            UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, port);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
            registry.bind("chat", stub);
            System.out.println("Server ready!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

   @Override
   public void adicionaCliente(String user) {

       this.listaClientes.add(user);

   }

   @Override
   public void retiraCliente(String userName) {
        Predicate<String> clientePredicate = cp -> 
        cp.equals(userName);
        listaClientes.removeIf(clientePredicate);
        try {
           Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
           registry.unbind(userName);
       } catch (RemoteException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (NotBoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   @Override
   public void recebeMensagem(Mensagem msg) {       

      try {
           Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
           for(String cliente : listaClientes) {
               if (!cliente.equals(msg.getRemetente())) {
                   Client stub = (Client) registry.lookup(cliente);
                   stub.printMensagem(msg);
               }                    
           }
       } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }


    public ArrayList<String> getListaClientes() {
        return listaClientes;
   }

   public void setListaClientes(ArrayList<String> listaClientes) {
       this.listaClientes = listaClientes;
   } 



  }
```

Client.java :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.Remote;

public class Client implements Remote, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6864579049922061838L;
    private static int port = 5002;
    private static String host = "127.0.0.1";

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        new Thread(new ClientInterface(host, port)).start();            
    }


    public void printMensagem(Mensagem mensagem) {
        System.out.println(mensagem.getRemetente() + ": " + mensagem.getMensagem());
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to make client stub method called on server print message on client screen?

The client doesn't have a stub. It isn't a remote object. It is a serializable object and it has been transported to the Registry holus bolus, and it runs in whatever JVM performed the `Registry.lookup()` to obtain it. This is not what you want. You want it to be a remote object, with a stub, so you have to make it implement a remote interface, and export it, and use it via its remote interface at the peer.

You also need to be aware that your present architecture won't work across more than one host, as you can't bind to a remote Registry. You will need to add a client registration method to the server.